# Passing a C/C++ socket into EM_ASM to use as websocket in Emscripten

Tags: c++, websocket, emscripten, webassembly

In my c++ program I would like to do something like this

```
int mySock = socket(...);
EM_ASM_({
        mySock.send("hello");
    },mySock);
```

What would be the correct way to pass the c++ socket so I can use it as a javascript websocket?

Comment: Note for anyone else reading this who's not familiar with Emscripten: Emscripten apparently comes with a library that simulates sockets by using websockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

BSD-style sockets in Emscripten C/C++ are websockets as WebAssembly lacks lower-level networking APIs for browsers.

So your objectives is passing C/C++ sockets to a `EM_ASM` JS block. After digging in Emscripten's source code [I found that `WS.sockets[id]` should work](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_websocket.js#L275):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int mySock = socket(...);

EM_ASM({  // Or MAIN_THREAD_EM_ASM instead.
  var ws = WS.sockets[$0];
  // Play with your socket here...
}, mySock);
```

I know it sounds undocumented hacky behavior, but at this moment you should deal with hacks when you want some low-level interops in Emscripten.

## Original (This is wrong, Ignore it)

BSD sockets in Emscripten C/C++ are websockets, due to lack of lower-level networking APIs for browsers.

So your objectives is passing C/C++ sockets to a `EM_ASM` JS block. After some searching [I found a hidden (undocumented) API called `FS.getStream()`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_fs.js#L400). I haven't test it yet as I don't have a proper test environment at the moment, but you can try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int mySock = socket(...);

EM_ASM_({  // Or MAIN_THREAD_EM_ASM instead.
  var stream = FS.getStream($0);
  var data = new Uint8Array(32);
  FS.write(stream, data, 0, data.length, 0);
}, mySock);
```

For more about the `FS` API (though `FS.getStream()` is one of few undocumented method) you can find it from [the Emscripten official documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#id2).

Comment: didn't make that clear but I already know I can use c++ send() for that example case and that emscripten c++ uses websockets under the hood, my example code is very simple just for explanation purposes, which means my problem is more complex but it simplifies to solving how to pass the c++ socket into EM_ASM()

Comment: I am not very sure about this but the emscripten File system API does not depend on the javascript websockets API

Comment: so I don't think the line `FS.write(stream, data, 0, data.length, 0);` will work but anyway maybe you mean that FS.getStream() is some kind of hack that will magically give me the javascript websocket variable

Comment: but if it really works, do you know how underneath it retrieves the variable, because that `FS.getStream()` hack may stop working in the future

Comment: @porente I'm sorry but I think I confused between Emscripten's UNIX socket implementation (SOCKFS) and ordinary socket implementation. Maybe I was drinking too much beer in the friday night ;) I updated the answer.